# Coturn string values only accepted when length is divisible by 4

Tags: c#, utf-8, turn, coturn

I am running a coturn server on an Azure virtual machine running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. I am implementing a TURN client in c# and I am struggling with what I'm assuming is either an issue in my server configuration, a bug in the server software, or an encoding issue in my client.

I first noticed the issue when I would receive the `REALM` from the server. The realm name was 9 characters but I kept getting 3 additional `NULL` characters from the server. My suspicions were confirmed when trying to change the software version I was sending. If the length was not divisible by 4, the server would send back nothing (I now believe it was silently discarding the message per the appropriate [STUN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389)/[TURN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5766) spec which prescribes discarding with unknown attributes).

Per the spec, I am encoding the strings as `UTF-8` (Example of storing string type TLV attribute)

```
private void StoreString(AttributeType key, string v, byte[] msg, ref int offset)
{
    byte[] stringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(v);

    // Attribute header
    StoreAttributeType(key, msg, ref offset);
    msg[offset++] = (byte)(stringBytes.Length >> 8);
    msg[offset++] = (byte)(stringBytes.Length & 0xFF);

    Array.Copy(stringBytes, 0, msg, offset, stringBytes.Length);
    offset += stringBytes.Length;
}
```

Raw bytes:

```
01-13-00-40-21-12-A4-42-57-9E-20-40-86-81-34-F9-B0-64-C1-E4-00-09-00-10-00-00-04-01-55-6E-61-75-74-68-6F-72-69-7A-65-64-00-15-00-10-39-64-38-35-62-66-61-66-62-63-34-36-30-62-31-66-00-14-00-09-74-65-73-74-72-65-61-6C-6D-00-00-00-80-22-00-04-4E-6F-6E-65
```

Which I parse using the spec and get

```
Type: AllocateErrorResponse, Length: 64, ID: 42a41221-9e57-4020-8681-34f9b064c1e4
Attributes:
- Type: ErrorCode, Value: Code: Unauthorized, Reason: Unauthorized
- Type: Nonce, Value: 9d85bfafbc460b1f
- Type: Realm, Value: testrealm

Attribute parsing not implemented for 0
- Length: 128, Value: 22-00-04-4E-6F-6E-65
```

The value it attempts to parse with `type=0` and `length=128` is actually the end of the message and the server software name

```
80-22-00-04-4E-6F-6E-65
```

Attribute `8022` is defined as attribute `SOFTWARE`, The length is `0x0004` and the value `4E-6F-6E-65` is the text `None`

So the server is returning all of the correct values and all of the correct lengths but it seems strings are being padded to UTF-16 divisible lengths. So this seems to be an encoding issue but I don't know if it is a software bug in the server, a configuration issue on the server, or an issue in my client. I know this is all open source and I can dig into the source code, but I'm hoping someone has some insight before I have to go that far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... This is what happens when you don't pay close enough attention to the RFC...

```
RFC 5389

15.  STUN Attributes

    After the STUN header are zero or more attributes.  Each attribute
    MUST be TLV encoded, with a 16-bit type, 16-bit length, and value.
    Each STUN attribute MUST end on a 32-bit boundary.  As mentioned
    above, all fields in an attribute are transmitted most significant
    bit first.
```

So it looks like the key is that **Each STUN attribute MUST end on a 32-bit boundary**. Therefore, when reading my 9 character realm, the remaining bytes should be read and discarded.